# Find the expected value and the variance of the weight of a person

Tags: probability

In room number one there are three women that weigh $61,57,59$ kg

In room number two there are three men that weigh $68,72,73$ kg

choosing one room randomly and picking a person,

> $\color{blue}{A)}$ find the expected value of the wight of a person and the variance
>
> $\color{blue}{B)}$ find the expected value of the wight of a person and the variance if we know that the person is from room number one

My try:

$$\color{blue}{A)}\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{6}(61+57+59+68+72+73)=\boxed{65}$$

$$\mathbb{V}(X)=\frac{1}{6}[(61-65)^2+(57-65)^2+(59-65)^2+(68-65)^2+(72-65)^2+(73-65)^2]$$

$$\color{blue}{B)}\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{3}(61+59+57)=\boxed{29.5}$$

$$\mathbb{V}(X)=\frac{1}{3}[(61-65)^2+(57-65)^2+(59-65)^2]$$

> My attempt is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using the same name $X$ for both A & B.
I suggest $E(X)$ and $V(X)$ for A and $E(X|R=1)$ and $V(X|R=1)$ for B, where $R$ is the room.

Second, I think you are computing the expectation in B incorrectly, you wrote division by 3 but actually divided by 6. The actual expectation is $E(X|R=1)=59$.

Accordingly, you need to subtract 59, not 65 from each value when you are computing $V(X|R=1)$.

Comment: Except from that things  that you mentioned, the rest looks ok to you?

Comment: yes, the rest lgtm